# Hashicorp Vault. Kubernetes Auth

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

Could you please say. I'm add in the volt-agent to the main pod. The secret of the norms is drawn from the volt and added to the pod, along the path /vault/secrets/credentials.txt in the format

```
last_vault_rotation: 2020-12-02T12:37:20.440116271+06:00
password: <password>
rotation_period: 604800
ttl: 506735
username: <username>
```

Deploying into kuber using helm. Question: how to make sure that the pod sees the credentials (lying in the pod file system) and pulls them up to connect to the database?
I'm added this code to Helm Deployment file

```
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: "true"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-status: "update"
        vault.hashicorp.com/role: "k8s_doc_user-test"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-db-creds: "database/static-creds/doc_user-test-rotate"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-db-creds: |
          {{`{{- with secret "database/static-creds/doc_user-test-rotate" -}}
        postgres://{{ .Data.data.username }}:{{ .Data.data.password }}@<ip-addr>:5432/aux_db?sslmode=disable
        {{- end }}`}}
```

But not working

Comment: I'm struggling to understand anything you've said. Is this output from google translate?

Comment: Please edit your question because it is not clear what do you want to do.